# make holes with subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I want to model a mobile telephone with holes in it and I want apply subdivision surface modifier. When I did apply it it became just crazy. As images down shows the circular holes became strange and extra mesh shows up. I want to make a hole for the camera as example and then for the flash ant etc...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on what you gave us, it's impossible to help you. Explain exactly what doesn't work and what you tried to achieve. Consider uploading your [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: sorry I forgot to explain why XD.

Comment: The beginning of this tutorial will tell you everything you need to know https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/smash-an-iphone

Comment: Check here how to make holes for Subsurf modifier: http://topologyguides.com/image/124120926080